# Sending Name Value Pair in POST using Jersey Client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, name-value

How can i pass name value pairs as body to a POST ReST Service in Jersey. Something similar to the code below using Apache Commons PostMethod

```
    final PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
    post.setRequestBody(new NameValuePair[] {
            new NameValuePair("loginId", userId),
            new NameValuePair("logonPassword", password),
            new NameValuePair("signature", signature),
            new NameValuePair("timestamp", timestamp),
            new NameValuePair("sourceSiteId", sourceSiteId) });
```

I'm porting this call to my application. The current call uses apache commons PostMethod. In my application i used Jersey. So i want to use the jersey classes/features instead of apache.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a [MultivaluedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) interface in `JAX-RS` with a 'MultivaluedMapImpl' in Jersey.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://site.com/resource");
MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
map.put("loginId", loginId);
...
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
             .post(ClientResponse.class, map);
```

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with) is a more comprehensive example of how to use Jersey client API.