# converting curl api call into restful api call

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, curl, jersey, soapui

i am very new to the java EE.

I have built some simple restful client for calling rest api's from java using jersey framework.

I have one curl request which i have to call from java

curl -i -X POST 'https://{url}' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H "Accept: application/vnd.newbay.dv-1.8+json" -H "X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE: DELETE" -H "X-Client-Platform: SERVICES" -H "X-Client-Identifier: IL" --insecure **--data 'path=%2FMy+Samsung+GT-I9082%2F20130822_172409.jpg&path=%2FMy+Samsung+GT-I9082%2F20130905_085407.jpg'**

Here the paths of file are passed as form post in curl using --data.

Can anyone tell me how to call this api from my java program using jersey framework? I am having difficulty because of this --data part? how exactly i will pass that in my restful java client that i cant understand.

Also can anyone tell me how to pass form post --data part while calling the same api from soapUI?

Answer (score 0):

In your cURL command, `--data` provides post data in a classic html form format. You shoud alrealy be aware of that because the content-type is explicit : `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Jersey can handle this encoding for you, using `MultivaluedMapImpl`.

see [Sending Name Value Pair in POST using Jersey Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529714/sending-name-value-pair-in-post-using-jersey-client)